# How do I add space in between a vertical stacking column for mobile in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have four images that go across horizontally on a desktop in bootstrap. On mobile, I want these images to stack vertically (which they do). Only problem is there is no vertical spacing between the images when they stack vertically on mobile. Is there a bootstrap style that I can add so it's stacks vertically on mobile?

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/ccP5Q7o6a0

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="section-heading">How it Works</h2>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/apple_PNG40.png">
          <p class="text-center">You need an apple</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/apple_PNG40.png">
          <p class="text-center">You need an orange</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/apple_PNG40.png">
          <p class="text-center">You need a pineapple</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/apple_PNG40.png">
            <p class="text-center">You need a melon</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your CSS please? Better yet, include an example of the problem in a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)**

Answer (score 1):

For **Bootstrap 5** just add gutter class on the row wrapping the column.

For Vertical Spacing:

```
<div class="row gy-5"></div>
```

This would add a vertical space between the columns.

For Horizontal Spacing:

```
<div class="row gx-5"></div>
```

This would add a horizontal space between the columns.

Keep Coding !

Answer (score 0):

Use your own media query to perform the task in question, if required.

Add a class to the row:

```
<div class="row myclass">
```

Then add a media query to handle it at the desired width

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .myclass > div {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Something like the above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap `visible-xs` class that only displays on the smallest screens..

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs"><br></div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/UfC6tohHa7